# Keep Popover centered relative to a button

Tags: css

I am experimenting with this CSS popover found http://codepen.io/derekpcollins/pen/JCLhG/. Here is the code to the popover.

```
.popover {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: 42px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
    left: -95px;
    padding: 7px 10px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

and on hover, the popover looks like this

[image]

I want to make the popover wider, but when I change the width to, say, 600px, it becomes misaligned.

[image]

What do I do if I want the arrow of the popover pointing to the button no matter how wide it is?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you want the popover to be any *dynamic* width  and centered, remove the `width`, set `white-space:nowrap` and change the positioning to

```
left: 50%;
transform:translateX(-50%);
white-space: nowrap;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #e3fbff;
}

/* Just to center things */
.center {
  margin: 75px auto;
  width: 30px;
}

/* The element to hover over */
.qs {
  background-color: #02bdda;
  border-radius: 16px;
  color: #e3fbff;
  cursor: default;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
.qs .popover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  border-radius: 5px;
  bottom: 42px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  color: #fff;
  display: none;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica',sans-serif;
  padding: 7px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 4;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.qs .popover:before {
  border-top: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  bottom: -7px;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -7px;
  position: absolute;
}
.qs:hover .popover {
  display: block;
  -webkit-animation: fade-in .3s linear 1, move-up .3s linear 1;
  -moz-animation: fade-in .3s linear 1, move-up .3s linear 1;
  -ms-animation: fade-in .3s linear 1, move-up .3s linear 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes fade-in {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes move-up {
  from {
    bottom: 30px;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 42px;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes move-up {
  from {
    bottom: 30px;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 42px;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes move-up {
  from {
    bottom: 30px;
  }
  to {
    bottom: 42px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <span class="qs">? <span class="popover above">Hey bro, cool popover!</span></span>
</div>

<div class="center">
  <span class="qs">? <span class="popover above">Short popover!</span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It does not work, because the position is specified with `px` value, so you would have to adjust the `width` and the `position` (in this case the `left` property).

If you want a solution that works **dynamically** (means **for all possible widths**) I suggest the following. Just add / change the following properties on class `.popover`:

```
    width: 600px; /* whatever you want */
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
```

**See [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOqpoP)**